# android - Keep bluetooth connection between activities?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

let's say i have 2 activities called `Activity A` and `Activity B`

i display list of devices on `Activity A` that users can connect to.
when users clicked one of the devices, it will connected to selected bluetooth device and exchange some data first to verify credentials (i.e. login). i have done this part.

when the data is correct i want to move to `Activity B` where all the main menu is there but i want to keep that connection made before in `Activity A` so that i don't need to disconnect and reconnect the connection again.

how to do that ? i'm new about this, please help me..

i use this library for the connection : 
https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle

thanks before :)

Comment: hi @Nabil Baadillah, I am facing the same problem, if u solved it, then  can u share your GitHub repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, I would move all Bluetooth code to a Service. Then you would not be tied to any specific activity.

Comment: could you be more specific about that ? i'm still new on this, thanks

Comment: Create a Service which would be started on app startup and killed when app is off (the second one will be done automatically unless you make it a sticky service).

Then do all of the Bluetooth stuff in that Service instead of the Activity, as you do now. This way, your activities will be using Bluetooth from the Service, and nothing will be tied to any of the activities themselves.

You can read more about services here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm or here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: You can create a service to do all the bluetooth stuff.And don't forget to use activity by binding to the service..the initial Activity should `startService()` and `bindService()`  once second activity is launched it should only `bindService()`

Comment: i finally manage to do that inside service :) thank you for pointing it out (@RobertK. @Pzy64)

Comment: @NabilBaadillah How did you make it work? can you share your code or github repo?

Comment: @NabilBaadillah Hey, I am also facing the same issue, during screen navigation from one activity to another BLE device disconnect and I am losing data. Can you please share your code.